# How to concatenate rows with similar IDs in multiple TSV files in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three tsv files with names; file1.tsv, file2.tsv anf file3.tsv

The three tsv files have the following column names;

- ID
- Comment

Now I want to create a tsv file, where each ID gets a concatenated 'comment' string by checking the three files.

For example;

```
file1.tsv
ID            Comment
Anne Smith    Comment 1 of Anne smith
Peter Smith   Comment 1 of peter smith

file2.tsv
ID            Comment
John Cena     Comment 2 of john cena
Peter Smith   Comment 2 of peter smith

file3.tsv
ID            Comment
John Cena     Comment 3 of john cena
Peter Smith   Comment 3 of peter smith
```

The results file should be;

```
results.tsv
ID            Comment
Anne Smith    Comment 1 of Anne smith
John Cena     Comment 2 of john cena. Comment 3 of john cena.
Peter Smith   Comment 1 of peter smith. Comment 2 of peter smith. Comment 3 of peter smith
```

I am new to panda. Just wondering if we can use Pandas or any other suitable library to perform concatenation rather than writing from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you read your tsv into df1, df2, df3

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df2]).groupby('ID').Comment.apply('. '.join)
```

Comment: Thank you :) `df1 = pd.read_csv( input_file, header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3 )` likewise. I hope this is correct syntax :)

Comment: Just wondering how to write `df` as a tsv file? Still couldn't find syntax for it.

Comment: @J Cena see my post for the write part.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Pandas' [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function, but with the `sep` argument set to `\t`.

If you use this on all three TSV files, you should end up with three dataframes. You can then use the [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) function to combine them how you wish.

Answer (score 1):

to further expand on Wen's answer, the last loop is not very panda-ic, but it works...

```
file1 = '''ID\tComment
Anne Smith\tComment 1 of Anne smith
Peter Smith\tComment 1 of peter smith
'''
file2 = '''ID\tComment
John Cena\tComment 2 of john cena
Peter Smith\tComment 2 of peter smith
'''

file3 = '''ID\tComment
John Cena\tComment 3 of john cena
Peter Smith\tComment 3 of peter smith
'''

flist=[]
for r in [file1,file2,file3]:
  fname=r+'.tsv'
  with open(fname,'w') as f:
    f.write(r)
  flist.append(fname)

import pandas as pd

dflist=[]
for fname in flist:
  df=pd.read_csv(fname,delimiter='\t')
  dflist.append(df)

grouped=pd.concat(dflist).groupby('ID')

data=[]
for row in grouped:
  data.append({'ID':row[0],'Comments':'. '.join(row[1].Comment)}) 

pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','Comments']).to_csv('concat.tsv',sep='\t',index=False)
```